# usage of A synchronous TCP daytime client

Tags: c++, boost, tcpclient, asyncsocket

I was going to compile the example in this link:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime1/src.html

so I tried to compile and run this code but I do not know what are the command line arguments. I mean client and host ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `localhost` as the `<host>` and run both the `server` & `client` programs on the same machine.